# Uncaught TypeError: addEventListener

Tags: null, addeventlistener, typeerror

Experiencing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null error

```
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var value = document.getElementById('item').value;
    if (value) {
        addItem(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `null` variables as follows too

```
if ( some_variable == null ){
    // some_variable is either null or undefined
}
```

In your case try

```
if (value !== null) {
    addItem(value);
}
```

> Edit

I checked the code segment you provided furthermore. 
It seems to be right.
can you please refer to this code segment.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var value = document.getElementById('item').value;
    if (value) {
   alert(value);
    }else{
     alert('null');
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="item" name="number" value=""/><br/> 
<input type="button" value="Button"  id="btn"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this solution didn't work me